# OCaml: Iterating through a list and skipping elements if of the wrong constructor

Tags: function, pattern-matching, ocaml, loops

This may seem like an odd thing to do, and you're certainly welcome to suggest a better way to do it.

Here's my goal:

I want to scroll through each element of a list passed into a function.  If it's of constructor Y, then I want to call some function on it.  If it's of constructor Z, I want to skip it.

If there's a way to check this in an if statement, then that seems like the way to go since I don't need to write an else.  However, I only know how to check this in a match.

For example:

```
let myFunct list = 
List.iter (fun x -> match x with
           | Y y -> otherFunction y
          ) list;;
```

Now, this gives me a warning about not being able to handle Z.  So I could throw something in there like...

```
let myFunct list = 
List.iter (fun x -> match x with
           | Y y -> otherFunction y
           | Z z -> (*skip*)
          ) list;;
```

Of course, I can't just leave Z's match blank....

How can I accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Comment: (Just a terminology note.  All elements of a list are of the same type.  OCaml's strong typing enforces this.  You're talking about different constructors of the *same* type.)

Comment: I would recommend not using the word "type" in a way that implies that a same list can contain elements of different types. "Constructor" is a possible less overloaded synonym.

Comment: "fun x -> match x with Y y -> ... | Z z -> ..." can be written more simply as "function Y y -> ... | Z z -> ..."

Answer (score 6):

Just return unit (ie, `()`) the `Z` case.

Are you sure you want `List.iter`.  It is primarily used to apply a function for its side effect.

A more idiomatic approach in functional programs is to filter the list using `List.filter` and then apply a transformation to all the remaining elements using `List.map`.

Comment: I do not agree that applying `List.filter` first to create an intermediate list that will be immediately discarded before applying `List.map` is good style.

Comment: @Pascal I think it is a good academic technique for someone who is new to functional languages.

Comment: `List.filter_map` for the rescue

Answer (score 1):

You could use `List.filter` to filter the list based on the condition, then use `List.iter` on the filtered list.

See the docs here for more info about the methods in the list module. http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/List.html

I don't have access to the OCaml compiler at the moment but the code would look something like this:

`List.iter (fun x -> ....) (List.filter (fun x -> ...) mylist)`

Comment: I don't understand how I'd use List.filter here.  As far as I know, having a certain constructor is not a condition one can check for but would need to match for.  Am I incorrect?  How would I accomplish this?

Comment: My problem is how to match based on constructor, and I would still have to do this in the filter function.

Comment: @CaseyPatton ah ok - I missed the main point of your question. Yes you still would need to use a match statement. I don't know of any other way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Lambdageek's answer for `List.iter` is right.  You just need to use () as your result in any case where you don't have anything to do.  All the different cases of your `match` expression should return () when you're doing an iteration.  That's what `List.iter` is all about.

Everyone else is (rightly, in my opinion) worried that you might not really want to use `List.iter`.  It might be the first thing you think of when coming from other (imperative) languages, but iteration *per se* isn't at all as commonly used when doing functional programming.  If you're learning OCaml in a course of some kind, it's even less likely that you want to use `List.iter`.  A course on OCaml would definitely begin by covering the *functional* parts.  To think functionally you want to think about transforming values from one form to another (i.e., applying functions to them).

Let's say you did want to use `List.filter`.  Then, as you say, you'll end up doing a `match` expression, but instead of returning () in all the different cases, you'd want to return a Boolean (true or false) in each case.  If you return true, the value will be included in the resulting list.  If you return false, the value won't be included in the resulting list.  Once again, that's what `List.filter` is all about.  Here's some code that returns a new list containing just the elements of a given list that have a Z constructor.

```
let myFunc list =
    List.filter
        (fun x -> match x with Z _ -> true | _ -> false)
        list
```

I'm not sure this helps, but I think what I'm trying to say is that using `match` isn't difficult.  You just need to cover every case.  This is good, you want your code to work in every case!